# Error while running my existing react native project for iOS

Tags: javascript, android, ios, swift, react-native

I am working on an existing react native project which is working fine in Windows OS but when I'm going to run it in Mac OS for iOS part, it throws me some error also I don't know if we solve this error then how much next errors are waiting for me.

`Cannot initialize parameter of type 'NSArray<id<RCTBridge... RCTCxxBridge.mm`

Package.json file

```
  "name": "SaveAMeal",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.2.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/progress-bar-android": "^1.0.3",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "native-base": "^2.12.1",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.8",
    "react-native-check-box": "^2.1.7",
    "react-native-device-info": "^5.5.3",
    "react-native-fetch-blob": "^0.10.8",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-iap": "^4.4.2",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-masked-text": "^1.13.0",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^0.7.0",
    "react-native-orientation": "^3.1.3",
    "react-native-popup-dialog": "^0.18.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.2",
    "react-native-responsive-fontsize": "^0.1.8",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.6",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-size-matters": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-star-rating": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-view-pdf": "^0.10.2",
    "react-native-wheel-pick": "^1.0.9",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-number-format": "^4.4.1",
    "react-phone-number-input": "^3.0.21",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.4",
    "@types/react-phone-number-input": "^3.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.5",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.54.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts/"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: https://infinitbility.com/build-failed-after-update-xcode-12.5

Comment: Not working getting the same error again.